# Destructuring JSON Request using TypeScript ( Nest JavaScript application)

Tags: node.js, json, nestjs

I am Quite new to Nest JavaScript/ type script. I am in the learning stage. But my client assigned a task to save user request in two tables. Here is the JSON request from user

`{"title":"TITLE","groups":[{"group_id":1,"nutrients":[{"nutrient_id":1,"quantity":2,"unit":"mg"},{"nutrient_id":2,"quantity":2,"unit":"g"}]},{"group_id":2,"nutrients":[{"nutrient_id":2,"quantity":2,"unit":"mg"},{"nutrient_id":3,"quantity":2,"unit":"g"}]}]}`
In profile table I need to save only title and timestamp. In nutrients table I need to save last inserted profile id, group id, nutrient id, quantity, and unit.
`First of all i am not able to de structure the User input in proper way`. By the way, I have created related module, controller, entity, and service functionalities.But stuck up at Service functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not map over the array and build the desired data to be fed into the entity? For instance...

```
  // Note:- Assuming the Json you shared is stored inside `const data`

  const profile = await ProfileEntity.create({ title: data.title })

  const nutrientsData = data.groups.flatMap(item => {
    return item.nutrients.map(({ quantity, nutrient_id, unit }) => {
        return {
            group_id: item.group_id,
            profile_id: profile.id,
            nutrient_id,
            unit,
            quantity
        }
    })
  })

  await NutrientsEntity.create(nutrientsData);
```

Comment: can  you please suggest me best resource to learn Typescript ? like any udemy video/ youtube channel etc ... Thank you very much

Comment: There's good crash course available for Typescript on youtube by Academind. If you want to dive deep into advanced typescript then you could checkout the Typescript course on Udemy by Maximilian Schwarzmüller (Academind)

Comment: Ok, thank you for your reply. I will purchase